# How do you call a method from a class depending on what button is chosen?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

The code below calculates the tax of an income input that is given through a `JTextField`. Each respective class (`ResidentTaxPayer`, `ForeignResidentTaxPayer` and `WorkingTaxPayer`) has its own method called `calcTax()`.

The code below works up until the `ActionListener` for Calculate. In this action a string - `StringIncome` - is declared and initialized to an income value which is a `JTextField`. This `JTextField` is then converted to a double and assigned to a double value: `totalIncome`. Finally `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog()` is used to call the `calcTax()` method in the `ResidentTaxPayer` class. This returns a correct calculation.

The code up to this point is fine if only dealing with a single Taxpayer instance. However I have designed my program to use `JButton`s to choose from a list (not actually an `ArrayList` just so no one gets confused) of 3 possible choices. I chose to ask my question like this to show everyone the sort of code I want/input for all buttons.

My code after the `ActionListener` for Calculate only changes the message title for whatever button is chosen.

My question for you all is how do I code my program so that, for instance if the `residentTaxPayerButton` is chosen then the income is passed to the `calcTax()` method in that class and the appropriate calculations are done. But if the `NonResidentTaxPayer` button is chosen then the income is passed so its `calcTax()` method and the appropriate calculations are done.

Would the `isSelect()` method be appropriate here? Or would you need to call the method from the button listeners?

Just in case anyone asks, the respective code for the classes are irrelevent to the question. This is an issue with my GUI **and not** the taxpayer classes. Those classes work fine without the use of the GUI.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

class personalFrame {

    private String title = "";
    JTextField Income = new JTextField(10);
    private JFrame personalTaxFrame = new JFrame("Personal Tax Calculator");
    JButton Calculate = new JButton("Calculate");

    ButtonGroup Tax = new ButtonGroup();
    JRadioButton residentTax = new JRadioButton("Resident Tax");
    JRadioButton nonresidentTax = new JRadioButton("Non-Resident Tax");
    JRadioButton workingTax = new JRadioButton("Working Tax");

    public personalFrame() {

        personalTaxFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        personalTaxFrame.setSize(300, 100);
        personalTaxFrame.setVisible(true);
        personalTaxFrame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        personalTaxFrame.add(new JLabel("Total Income "));

        personalTaxFrame.add(Income);
        personalTaxFrame.add(Calculate);

        Tax.add(residentTax);
        personalTaxFrame.add(residentTax);

        Tax.add(nonresidentTax);
        personalTaxFrame.add(nonresidentTax);

        Tax.add(workingTax);
        personalTaxFrame.add(workingTax);

        Calculate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                String stringIncome = Income.getText();
                Double totalIncome = Double.parseDouble(stringIncome);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Tax payable is A$" + ResidentTaxPayer.calcTax(totalIncome), title, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

            }

        });

        residentTax.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ie) {

                title = "Resident Tax";


            }
        });

        nonresidentTax.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ie) {

                title = "Non-resident Tax";

            }
        });

        workingTax.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ie) {

                title = "Working Tax";

            }
        });

    }
}
```

common interface

```
public interface TaxProfile {

    double getPayableTax();
    public String getTaxID();
    public String getNameOfTaxPayer();
}
```

```
    TaxProfile taxProfile;//create TaxProfileField


    residentTax.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ie) {
                taxProfile.getPayableTax(); //use field to call interface method
                title = "Resident Tax";

            }
        });
```

Comment: You don't have to necessarily perform the calculation in those action listeners. If you want the choice and the actual calculation be triggered by separate buttons you can do that. How? For example: Make an enum of the possible choices, have the form have a field of that enum type, have the choice-buttons set it along with title, then check its value in Calculate's listener and call into the appropriate class.

Comment: Unrelated: Reconsider your choice of a floating point type. You are obviously dealing with monetary amounts. See the links mentioned in: https://codemonkeyism.com/once-and-for-all-do-not-use-double-for-money/

Comment: @Fildor In my course we're highly encouraged to stay away from Enum use so that wouldnt be the correct way In this case. I do appreciate your answer though

Comment: Then use an int to represent your choices. The point is: Have a field hold your representation of "choice" and have the listener evaluate against this field to actually follow that choice. If all of the calculation classes implement a common interface, you could even directly use that for the field and have the buttons set the field to an instance of the respective type.

Comment: _"In my course we're highly encouraged to stay away from Enum use"_ - Just by dogma or do they actually tell you why? Obviously, they failed to give you the much more critical advice (see above "Unrelated" comment).

Comment: @Fildor The Professors who teach my course feel Enums are inefficient

Comment: @Fildor we have used Enums because its part of the course, but for this subject we have been told to avoid them

Comment: Check updated answer with example.

Comment: @Fildor Okay so i initilize it like this "TaxProfile calculationChoice = new ResidentTaxPayer()"

Comment: and then say i want to use it for WorkingTaxPayer i just add alculationChoice = new WorkingHolidayTaxPayer() in the button Listener for WorkingHolidayTaxPayer?

Answer (score 1):

There are different options here, working on a common base, which is:

- Make a new Field on the Form class that holds a representation of the desired calculation option.
- Make the choice-Buttons' listeners set that field to the respective represention
- Make the Calculate listener evaluate the field and call the corresponding method.

Your teacher discouraged using `enum`, which I can understand, but they gave you a really poor reason. Anyway, technically, you *could* use an enum.

You could use a numerical value ( for example `int` ). In that case, I'd introduce some well documented `const int` values to represent the choice. But that would be *very* similar to using an enum, so they are likely to disapprove of this, too.

There are even more, but the option I'd prefer would be:

Have all your calculation classes implement a common `interface`.
Then make the field (let's call it `calculationChoice`) have that interface type.

The choice-buttons' listeners would then just set for example `calculationChoice = new ResidentTaxPayer();` and the Calculation listener wouldn't even have to care anymore, it would just call `taxAmount = calculationChoice.calcTax(amount);`

---

Unrelated: try using BigDecimal instead of double and document results with different inputs for both types and compare them. You'd be surprised, I guess.

---

Example

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
         // ResidentTaxPayer is-a TaxProfile, so we can assign it like so:
         TaxProfile taxProfile = new ResidentTaxPayer();
        System.out.println("Payable Amount in US $: " + taxProfile.getPayableTaxAmount(5432.10));
         // so is NonResidentTaxPayer, so this is also valid
         taxProfile = new NonResidentTaxPayer();
        System.out.println("Payable Amount in US $: " + taxProfile.getPayableTaxAmount(5432.10)); // different result!
     }
}

public interface TaxProfile{
    double getPayableTaxAmount( double income );
}

public class ResidentTaxPayer implements TaxProfile {
    public double getPayableTaxAmount( double income )
    {
        double tax = 0.0;
        // calculate tax
        tax = income * 0.18; // Just a dummy
        return tax;
    }
}

public class NonResidentTaxPayer implements TaxProfile {
    public double getPayableTaxAmount( double income )
    {
        double tax = 0.0;
        // calculate tax
        tax = income * 0.24; // Just a dummy
        return tax;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a common interface amoungst them

Comment: ive added it to the question Code. Would i just use payableTax then as that overrights the calctax method

Comment: Great! Then you're halfway there.

Comment: when you say "Have all your calculation classes implement a common interface" by calculation classes do you mean my methods?

Comment: From the example code, I inferred, you'd have a `ResidentTaxPayer`, a `NonResidentTaxPayer` and a `WorkTax` class or similar, which all implement `TaxProfile` , right ?

Comment: That is correct. And all classes have their own CalcTax method

Comment: So, you can have a Field `TaxProfile taxProfile` which can be initialized with an instance of any of those classes. That means: your caller (the Form code) does not care, which one it is, it assumes, you initialized it with the correct one to use and just calls `taxProfile.getPayableTax()`. Depending on which implementation you used, the respective method will be called.

Comment: Maybe have a look at this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html

Comment: Do you mean make a TaxProfile object?

Comment: @DanielLu I'll add an example later.

Comment: so do you mean create a field of TaxProfile and then use it so call getPayAbleTax? ill add some code in my question

Comment: Check the bottom of my question ive updated the code.

Comment: so i just use this code " TaxProfile taxProfile = new ResidentTaxPayer();" in my personalFrame class and change it for what class instance i need?

Comment: basically, yes. Just that `TaxProfile taxProfile` would be a field of the Form class. The button listeners would set it accordingly to an instance of one of the implementing classes and your Calculation listener would just call the interface method on the form class field.

Comment: what do you mean by form class

Comment: Also should i change my interface so that payableTax takes a paramater?